# Second Monitor won't work on 15.04

Tags: nvidia, 15.04, xorg, multiple-monitors

My fresh ubuntu 15.04 install will not work with 2 monitors.  With one monitor everything is fine.  As soon as I plug in a second monitor I am logged out,everything I have open is closed and the logon screen flashes off and on on the original monitor while the second monitor remains blank.  Unplugging either the original monitor or the new monitor I have added results in the logon screen appears and I can log back in.  Booting up with both monitors plugged in causes the same problem.

I have tried both proprietary nvidia drivers and the nouveau drivers.  The same thing happens with both.  My graphics card is an Nvidia GTX 750Ti

This appears repeatedly in syslog each time I try and plug in a second monitor but doens't make much sense to me:

```
Oct 16 18:35:45 Ada kernel: [  743.523285] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] failed to load fuc409c
Oct 16 18:35:45 Ada acpid: client 9017[0:0] has disconnected
Oct 16 18:35:45 Ada acpid: client connected from 9229[0:0]
Oct 16 18:35:45 Ada acpid: 1 client rule loaded
Oct 16 18:35:46 Ada systemd[1]: Started Session c31 of user lightdm.
Oct 16 18:35:46 Ada systemd[1]: Starting Session c31 of user lightdm.
Oct 16 18:35:46 Ada org.a11y.atspi.Registry[9343]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
Oct 16 18:35:46 Ada kernel: [  744.427122] sound hdaudioC2D0: HDMI: invalid ELD data byte 76
Oct 16 18:35:46 Ada org.a11y.atspi.Registry[9343]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
Oct 16 18:35:46 Ada org.a11y.atspi.Registry[9343]: after 21 requests (21 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Oct 16 18:35:46 Ada org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[9332]: A connection to the bus can't be made
Oct 16 18:35:46 Ada org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[9332]: g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
Oct 16 18:35:46 Ada ca.desrt.dconf[9332]: g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
Oct 16 18:35:46 Ada kernel: [  744.545964] nouveau  [  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] using external firmware
Oct 16 18:35:46 Ada kernel: [  744.545974] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nv117_fuc409c failed with error -2
Oct 16 18:35:46 Ada kernel: [  744.545977] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/fuc409c failed with error -2
Oct 16 18:35:46 Ada kernel: [  744.545978] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] failed to load fuc409c
```

Both monitors work perfectly on the windows 7 install on the same computer.  Any assistance in working out what is going on and fixing it would be greatly appreciated.  I am out of my depth on this one.

Comment: Looks like you are using nouveau, try to install proprietary nvidia driver from software center.

Answer (score 0):

I installed xrandr on my computer for it to work. 
(This was the [solution for Arch-linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multihead) and OpenSuse)

```
apt-get install xrandr
```

followed by a command similar to:

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --auto --output HDMI1 --auto --right-of VGA1
```

should do the trick.

(places the previous screen (HDMI1) to the right of the specified screen (VGA1).)

Comment: Drivers didn't matter, as far as I remember.

Comment: I've tried various configurations using xrandr and it hasn't had any effect.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Oh it appears I didn't read the log at all.. sorry.
I found a similar [issue](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=191566), 
lspci | grep -E VGA , should reveal if you need the intel driver too

Comment: intel drivers are now installed and I still have exactly the same problem :(

Comment: Unfortunate..
Does the second monitor go into the (same) graphics card or into the motherboard? VGA or HDMI?

Comment: Both go into the graphics card, one VGA and one on HDMI

Comment: Then only the Nvidia driver should be needed. Have you tried using the nvidia control panel (GUI)?

"sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates nvidia-settings-updates"

"gksu nvidia-settings"

_Needs privileges to write config to /etc_

Comment: When I have both monitors connected I cannot get passed the login screen hence cannot open the nvidia control panel.